# Scala lazy collection growth

Tags: scala, collections, lazy-evaluation

This question is a bit more theoretical.
I have an object which holds a private mutable list or map, whose growth is append only.  I believe I could argue that the object itself is functional, being functionally transparent and to all appearances, immutable.  So for example I have

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

case class Foo(bar:String)

object FooContainer {
  private val foos = Map.empty[String, Foo]

  def getFoo(fooName:String) = foos.getOrElseUpdate(fooName, Foo(fooName))
}
```

I could do a similar case with lists.  Now I imagine to be truly functional, I would need to ensure thread safety, which I suppose I could do simply using locks, synchronise or atomic references.  My questions being is this all necessary & sufficient, is it a common practice, are there established patterns for this behaviour?

Comment: It's a quite common pattern used in memoization of functions. Scala's lazy vals are also implemented in a similar way. As long as the state changes are not observable from the outside (except for CPU timing variations), the function can be considered "pure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that "functional" is really the wrong term. The exact example shown above could be called "pure" in the sense that its output is only ever defined by its input, thus not having any (visible) side-effects. In reality it is impure though, since it has hidden internal state.

> The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change as program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

The apparent impurity vanishes though, if you make the `Foo` class mutable:

```
case class Foo(bar:String) {
    private var mutable:Int = 1
    def setFoo(x:Int) = mutable = x
    def foo = mutable
}
```

The mutability of the `Foo` class results in `getFoo` being impure:

```
scala> FooContainer.getFoo("test").foo
res5: Int = 1

scala> FooContainer.getFoo("bla").setFoo(5)

scala> FooContainer.getFoo("bla").foo
res7: Int = 5
```

In order for the function to be apparently pure, `FooContainer.getFoo("bla").foo` must always return the same value. Therefore, the "purity" of the described construct is fragile at best.

Comment: For your last point, you could argue that of any pure collection structure though no?  So a list of mutable objects is no longer pure, though it is not really the purity of the list itself that is at fault?

Comment: Yes, an immutable list containing mutable objects, imho, is not pure since the mutable internal state of its items make the list automatically have mutable internal state as well. Thus, if you want to be truly "pure", you just can't have mutable objects I guess :)

Comment: FYI: See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.127.8501 for so-called *observational purity*

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you're better off with a `var` holding an immutable collection type which is replaced when updated than you are with a `val` holding a mutable type. The former never deals in values that may change after being created (other than the class which holds the evolving value itself). Then you only need to be moderately careful about when updated values held by the `var` are published to it, but since updating a reference is generally atomic (apart from things like storing a `long` or a `double` to RAM on a 32-bit machine), there's little risk.